# Split excel file with two worksheets into multiple files with the same worksheets (one filtered)

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel file with two worksheets, one with the list of units, second with the lists needed for data validation. I need to split this file into multiple files, and each of them should have only specific unit in the first worksheet, and second worksheet should be intact.

I have found below code, however it creates the file with only first worksheet. Any advice how I can keep another one?

```
Sub ExportDatabaseToSeparateFiles()
'Export is based on the value in the KeyCol
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim mySht As Worksheet
    Dim myName As String
    Dim myArea As Range
    Dim myShtName As String
    Dim KeyCol As String
    Dim myField As Integer

    myShtName = ActiveSheet.Name
    KeyCol = "C"

    Set myArea = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range(KeyCol & "1").EntireColumn).Cells

    Set myArea = myArea.Offset(1, 0).Resize(myArea.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
    myField = myArea.Column - myArea.CurrentRegion.Cells(1).Column + 1

    For Each myCell In myArea
        On Error GoTo NoSheet
        myName = Worksheets(myCell.Value).Name
        GoTo SheetExists:
 NoSheet:
        Set mySht = Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets(1))
        mySht.Name = myCell.Value
        With myCell.CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter Field:=myField, Criteria1:=myCell.Value
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
                    mySht.Range("A1")
            mySht.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            .AutoFilter
        End With
        Resume
 SheetExists:
    Next myCell

    For Each mySht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If mySht.Name = myShtName Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            mySht.Move
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ActiveSheet.Name & ".xls"
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
        End If
    Next mySht
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry would you mind clarifying - do you mean that you want two worksheets split into two workbooks, without having the tabs present in each?

Comment: I need to split first worksheet into multiple files, basing on the values in specific column. But I also need to keep the second worksheet in those newly created files, but it should not be filtered, but kept as it is.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I would say that "ActiveWorkbook" is not the file you think it is.  Create a variable to hold the Workbook object and use it instead of "ActiveWorkbook".  Pretty much any time you use "Active..." anything, you risk losing control of what object you are really using.